# WPF. При биндинге к DataGrid, создаются строки но не заполняются данными

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

Есть следующий замл код :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Link}" Margin="5" ToolTip="Enter playlist id" Width="500" FontSize="20" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Content="Parse" Margin="5" Padding="10,5" FontSize="20" Command="{Binding ParseCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding InformationAboutSong}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Thumbnail" Width="200">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Song name" Width="260" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Artist name" Width="260" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Duration" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <DataGrid Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding InformationAboutPlaylist}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Playlist thumbnail" Width="300">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Playlist description" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

К DataGrids я прибиндил два свойста из VM :

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _link;

    public string Link
    {
        get { return _link; }
        set { _link = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("InformationAboutSong");
            OnPropertyChanged("InformationAboutPlaylist");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Track> _informationAboutSong;
    private Playlist _informationAboutPlaylist;

    public ObservableCollection<Track> InformationAboutSong
    {
        get => _informationAboutSong;
        set
        {
            _informationAboutSong = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InformationAboutSong));
        }
    }

    public Playlist InformationAboutPlaylist 
    {
        get => _informationAboutPlaylist;
        set
        {
            _informationAboutPlaylist = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InformationAboutPlaylist));
        }
    }


    private ICommand _parseCommand;
    public ICommand ParseCommand => _parseCommand ?? (_parseCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        MainModel mm = new MainModel();

        InformationAboutSong = mm.GetSongInfo(Link);
        InformationAboutPlaylist = mm.GetPlaylistInfo(Link);
    }));
}
```

Которые в свою очередь заполняются из методов GetSongInfo, GetPlaylistInfo :

```
public ObservableCollection<Track> GetSongInfo(string link)
    {
        string playlistId = link; // NEED PARSE

        ObservableCollection<Track> informationAboutSong = null;
        try
        {
            var yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = _APIKEY });
            var channelRequest = yt.Playlists.List("snippet");
            channelRequest.Id = playlistId;
            var channelResponse = channelRequest.Execute();

            Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Playlist playlist = channelResponse.Items[0];

            var playlistItemsListRequest = yt.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
            playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = playlistId;
            playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

            // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            var playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();

            informationAboutSong = new ObservableCollection<Track>();
            foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
            {
                WebClient myDownloader = new WebClient();
                myDownloader.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

                string jsonResponse = myDownloader.DownloadString(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + playlistItem.Snippet.ResourceId.VideoId + "&key="
                + _APIKEY + "&part=contentDetails");
                dynamic dynamicObject = Json.Decode(jsonResponse);
                string tmp = dynamicObject.items[0].contentDetails.duration;
                var songDuration = Convert.ToInt32(System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(tmp).TotalSeconds);

                Track track = new Track()
                {
                    ThumbnailUri = GetMaxResolution(playlistItem.Snippet.Thumbnails),
                    SongName = playlistItem.Snippet.Title,
                    ArtistName = playlist.Snippet.ChannelTitle,
                    Duration = $"{songDuration / 60}:{songDuration % 60}"
                };

                informationAboutSong.Add(track);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return informationAboutSong;
    }

    public Model.Playlist GetPlaylistInfo(string link)
    {
        string playlistId = link; // NEED PARSE

        Model.Playlist informationAboutPlaylist = null;

        try
        {
            var yt = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = _APIKEY });
            var channelRequest = yt.Playlists.List("snippet");
            channelRequest.Id = playlistId;
            var channelResponse = channelRequest.Execute();

            Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data.Playlist playlist = channelResponse.Items[0];


            var playlistItemsListRequest = yt.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
            playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = playlistId;
            playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

            // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
            var playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();

            foreach (var playlistItem in playlistItemsListResponse.Items)
            {
                informationAboutPlaylist = new Model.Playlist() // Значения в каждом playlistItem одинаковы, по этому берём только 1 экземпляр (последний).
                {
                    Thumbnail = GetMaxResolution(playlist.Snippet.Thumbnails),
                    Description = playlist.Snippet.Description
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        return informationAboutPlaylist;
    }
```

И при выполнении программы - в первом DataGrid создаются пустые строки, а во втором вообще ничего не происходит.

Comment: А привязка колонок к свойствам где? `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Song name" Width="260" />` тут вы создали колонку, ок, но как она должна узнать от куда брать информацию? Наверно должно быть `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Song name" Binding="{Binding Нужное свойство}" Width="260" />`? По поводу пустой таблицы, то делайте отладку, смотрите какие данные у вас приходят и есть ли в конечном итоге у привязанной коллекции данные.

Comment: В первом DataGrid колонки добавили, а указать, какая колонка какие данные забирает - не указали. Окрываем [первую ссылку в гугле](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/custom-columns/), смотрим на аттрибут `Binding="{Binding Name}"`

Comment: Так я же могу только свойства VM биндить. 
У меня в роли свойств выступают списки с данными (которые используют два моих созданных класса-контейнера для данных, в свойствах которых они и хранятся).
Или оно будет видеть колонки этих списков и я смогу по ним биндить? 
(надеюсь я понятно написал)

Comment: Вы попробуйте сначала, это секундное дело прописать биндинги.

Comment: Получилось. Но почему?
(Кроме нижнего дата грида, там почему то данные не отображаются, буду с отладчиком искать)

Comment: Посмотрел содержимое _informationAboutPlaylist
В двух полях есть данные, но почему то DataGrid не отображает их (даже строки не создаются как было до биндига колонок с первым DataGrid). 
Возможно в ItemSource нельзя прикрепить мой  
Playlist _informationAboutPlaylist; (с двумя полями - типа string). 
( Я только новичек, возможно задаю глупые вопросы, так что не бейте ногами:) )

Comment: "Почему?" - наверно потому, что так работает `DataGrid`? Если вы убираете автоматическое создание колонок и берете эту роль на себя, то будьте добры указать от куда эта колонка должна брать данные, из какого конкретно свойства. По поводу второго `DataGrid` вся ваша проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь привязать контрол, работающий с коллекциями к обычному классу (не коллекции). Тут вы либо делаете `public Playlist InformationAboutPlaylist` коллекцией (`public ObservableCollection<Playlist> InformationAboutPlaylist`), либо убираете `DataGrid` и делаете свою разметку, привязав все к этому свойству.

Comment: Понял, спасибо. 
Под "Почему", я имел ввиду следующее: 
Я думал что биндить можно только свойства моей VM, вот и удивился что оно "видит" свойства моих классов, которые я использую в реализации бизнес логики в Model, из другого пространства имён.

Comment: Могу ли я при биндинге, обратится к свойству класса? (Имею ввиду, что у меня в классе Playlist - два свойства, и мне их нужно прибиндить к моим контролам)
Или мне придётся тогда два свойства в VM создавать, что бы их прибиндить к Image & TextBlock ?

Comment: Можете, покажите классы `PlayList` и `Track`, отредактируйте вопрос. И у вас неправильная (бессмысленная) реализация свойства `Link`, обратите внимание на ту, что я вам дал в предыдущем вопросе.

Comment: Да, уже убедился что можно. Реализацию Link, исправил. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @nikitamanzhosov мне будет приятно, если вы пометите галочкой мой ответ на ваш прошлый вопрос. Спасибо. Отвечаю на "Почему?": потому что `DataContext` для колонки таблицы указывает на экземпляр объекта, предоставляющего данные таблице для заполнения строки. То есть на текущий элемент коллекции, привязанной к `DataGrid`. Просто и удобно. [Ссылка на документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Привязке без разнице что вы и как привязываете, главное чтобы это было публичное свойство с открытым `get`. То, что это VM/M - это уже удобство разработки приложения по правилам MVVM. У вас есть свойство `public ObservableCollection<Track> InformationAboutSong`, `Track` - это класс, который будет внутри коллекции и который будет отображаться, с него свойства и будут браться при привязке. Другое дело, что вы по сути нарушаете MVVM подход, ибо Model - это некая структура, которая получает данные из вне (файл, сайт, база и др.), а VM - это то, что общается с пользователем.

Comment: Я на вашем месте переписал проект по такой логике: Есть структура классов, которые работают с API ютуба (получают нужные данные, отправляют если надо и так далее), дальше сделал бы ViewModel, которая запрашивала у Model нужные данные для отображения и инициализировала только то, что необходимо для отображения (например в Model у вас свойства `Id`, `Name`, `Tag` и тд, а отобразить надо только Name, так зачем VM слою знать тот же `Tag`?), также пусть VM слой содержит команды, которые будут запрашивать из M слоя другие данные. У вас должно быть [такое](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/pics/22.1.png)